# How to print star like below in console application? I/p 5 O/p like = 1 212 32123 4321234 543212345

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Input is Five
Output need like above I tried

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Expect output , Input five

Comment: 1 212 32123 4321234 543212345 like this..